# Using Remote Control with AVPlayer in iOS 7 & 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am trying to write a simple personal radio app, and had an annoying problem.

I try to play a .pls (stream) file from a remote server with AVPlayer and I successfully managed to make it work. I can now play the stream but as I mentioned in the title, I can not remotely control the play/pause option when the app is in background.

I searched a lot on Internet about that topic and found two solutions.

1- As in Apple's [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW4) Documentation, using "MPRemoteCommandCenter" class to handle this, but for this solution I cannot find any good explanation that how am I going to use AVPlayer with it. This brings me to the second solution since I have no idea how to use MPRemoteCommandCenter class.

2- As almost all people mentioned about 
**remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:** method.
However when I try to use that approach I cannot get a respond. My **remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:** method is never been called. Here is my code's that how I implemented the behavior:

I have two classes, one called EGPlayRadio.m which contains the AVPlayer and AVAudioSession stuff, the other one is the EGMainMenuViewController.m which displays a play button and pause button to stream the radio.

- I payed attention to first call **[AVSession sharedInstance]** before calling **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]** method.
- Also I payed attention on that Giving the app background audio playing permission from build settings of the project.

**However, after searching a lot on Internet I can not find a suitable solution for my problem. Here are my two classes that I implemented:**

**EGPlayRadio.m**

```
#import "EGPlayRadio.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface EGPlayRadio () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioSession *audioSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;

@end

@implementation EGPlayRadio

- (id)initDefault
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://LINK-OF-THE-PLS-FILE"];
        _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)playRadio
{
    [self.player play];
}

- (void)pauseRadio
{
    [self.player pause];
}
```

**EGMainMenuViewController.m**

```
@interface EGRMainMenuViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EGPlayRadio *radioControl;

@end

@implementation EGRMainMenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.radioControl = [[EGPlayRadio alloc] initDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    self.pauseButton.enabled = NO;
    self.pauseButton.alpha = 0.3f;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)musicInteracted:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == self.playButton)
    {
        self.pauseButton.enabled = YES;
        self.pauseButton.alpha = 1.0f;
        self.playButton.enabled = NO;
        self.playButton.alpha = 0.3f;
        [self.radioControl playRadio];
    }
    else
    {
        self.pauseButton.enabled = NO;
        self.pauseButton.alpha = 0.3f;
        self.playButton.enabled = YES;
        self.playButton.alpha = 1.0f;
        [self.radioControl pauseRadio];
    }

}

-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            //[streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            //[streamer start];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            //[streamer pause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            //[streamer stop];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others having the same issue, I solved my problem by following:

In **EGPlayRadio.m** class, I allocated AVAudioSession by using

```
[_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
```

Insted of it we have to use:

```
[_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

That is the problem for me, after changing this, I can successfully receive the remote notifications.

Comment: But why? What if we really need those options?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @Onur Şahindur, I have this working finally after a couple years of struggling with this. Can't believe this isn't documented anywhere. As Onur said, there are many many of us on stackoverflow that have struggled with this, but this is the first solution that actually works.

I also got this working with the "MPRemoteCommandCenter" class. I implemented everything in the appDelegate with method calls to my singleton that manages my AVPlayer. Here is my solution:

```
_audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

// Previously, I used [_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&setCategoryError];
// As noted by @Onur, it has to be the following (without options)
[_audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

// Apple documentation says you don't need the following if you are using
// the MPRemoteCommandCenter, but that is not true. It is needed.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];


MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.nextTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.previousTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [[MediaController sharedInstance] playOrPauseMusic];    // Begin playing the current track.
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [[MediaController sharedInstance] playOrPauseMusic];    // Begin playing the current track.
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [[MediaController sharedInstance] playOrPauseMusic];    // Begin playing the current track.
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [[MediaController sharedInstance] fastForward];    // forward to next track.
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.previousTrackCommand addTargetWithHandler: ^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    [[MediaController sharedInstance] rewind];    // back to previous track.
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.stopCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.skipForwardCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.enableLanguageOptionCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.disableLanguageOptionCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.changeRepeatModeCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.changePlaybackRateCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.changeShuffleModeCommand setEnabled:NO];
// Seek Commands
[commandCenter.seekForwardCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.seekBackwardCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand setEnabled:NO];
// Rating Command
[commandCenter.ratingCommand setEnabled:NO];

// Feedback Commands
// These are generalized to three distinct actions. Your application can provide
// additional context about these actions with the localizedTitle property in
// MPFeedbackCommand.
[commandCenter.likeCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.dislikeCommand setEnabled:NO];
[commandCenter.bookmarkCommand setEnabled:NO];
```

In addition to the above (which I put in the appDelegate - application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), add this to your appDelegate also:

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then, every time you change the media item you are going to play, I execute the following code from within my media controller singleton:

```
ipodControlArtwork = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc]initWithImage:artworkImage];
if (artworkImage != nil && nowPlayingArtist != nil && nowPlayingTitle != nil && ipodControlArtwork != nil) {

    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                             nowPlayingTitle, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                                                             nowPlayingArtist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                                                             ipodControlArtwork, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork,
                                                             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0], MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate, nil];
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'MediaController' give me this error @JeffB6688

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. It is well documented in Apple's documentation.